# Unable to stop and start tomcat server properly using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

Hi I have a problem with the below commands.

```
REM : Start server
C:
cd C:\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\bin
CALL shutdown.bat
cd C:\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\webapps
RMDIR ProjectWAR /S /Q
DEL ProjectWar.war
cd C:\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\bin
catalina jpda start
```

I am trying to shutdown the tomcat server, then delete the project folder and war file and then again start the tomcat server.

But if I run the above code, server is getting shutdown, then only war file is getting deleted (not the projectWar folder) and nothing else. Please help me.

Comment: Do you see any errors when the file runs the `RMDIR ProjectWAR /S /Q` ?

Comment: Maybe there are some files _locked_ under your project folder?

Comment: @JosefZ 
Firstly, can you please tell me whether the above code piece has any errors? Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any errors in your code provided, it looks well. However,  there is  a hidden `shutdown.bat` content... I'd add `pause` at the end and preset `echo ON` in both scripts. Follow @theglossy1 and make public all error messages...

Answer (score 1):

```
taskkill /f /t /im java.exe
timeout /t 30
pushd "tomcatHome\bin\"
call startup.bat
```

/f = force-quit

/t = stops the task and any subtasks

/im = image name of the process

[taskkill docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)

Comment: Please, *do not use the comments space to add code* - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your post instead!

Answer (score 0):

When you call the shutdown command, the next commands don't wait for the server to shut down. The folder doesn't get deleted because it is still being used by the server (which is in the process of shutting down but not actually shutting down). So when it's done, the server is shutdown and the war is deleted (because nothing is using the war), but the folder is still there because when the delete command was called it was in use.